# Fresh installation of openshift origin - router and registry services missing

Tags: openshift-origin

I am installing openshift origin on centos using this tutorial: https://www.stevem.io/post/getting-started-with-openshift-v3-on-vmware/
Ansible installation was successful, I can see kubernetes node status:

```
[root@os-m-01 ~]# oc get nodes
NAME               STATUS                     AGE
os-m-01.mydomain   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   43m
os-n-01.mydomain   Ready                      42m
os-n-02.mydomain   Ready                      43m
os-n-03.mydomain   Ready                      42m
os-n-04.mydomain   Ready                      43m
```

DNS was set up correctly.
But when I do

```
[root@os-m-01 ~]# oc get svc
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                 AGE
kubernetes   172.30.0.1   <none>        443/TCP,53/UDP,53/TCP   50m
```

I don't see services mentioned in the tutorial - docker-registry, registry-console, router. 
How can I debug this problem? 
How do I filter errors in openshift logs? journalctl -p only start displaying messages on info level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had wrong ansible host inventory - section nodes must contain master node(s) and label 'region':'infra'